# Drawn current from a two and single supply Class B power amplifier

Tags: power, power-amplifier

I was reading a section from a book that talks about class B amplifier. I don't quite understand what the author meant by the highlighted part. Can someone help me picture what the author is trying to convey? I know what full-wave and rectified signals are but I can't quite connect it to what the book is saying.

[image]

Comment: Do you know that class-B  = push-pull stage?

Comment: Yes, I know that. But why the distinction between the form of current drawn for both single and dual supply? What I'm thinking is that for both single supply and dual supply the form of the current is half wave rectified signal. Since both transistors in the pushpull alternates. I'm confused.

Comment: A mistake/error?

Comment: What do you mean? Are  you refering to the author? Please bear with me. English is my secondary language.

Comment: The error in the book. Because in a single supply circuit for a "positive" cycle the current form supply is used to charge the coupling capacitor. And for the negative half cycle, the PNP discharge this capacitor and at the same time NPN is cut-off thus, no current is drawn form power supply.   Did you try to find the errata for the book.?

Comment: A BTL amplifier with two amplifiers and a bridged load would act as described.

Comment: @KevinWhite What do you mean by BTL? Why is there a difference in the form of current drawn between the single and dual supply?

Comment: @Paumdrdo - "Bridge Tied Load". Using two amplifiers in anti-phase to drive a single load with twice the voltage that could be achieved normally. Often used in car stereo amplifiers.